# Mysql Bind insert with classes : unable to insert with oops

Tags: php, mysqli

I am just learning classes , i am trying to add data using mysql bind params but unable to do so , seems some silly mistake , please help me with is , i want to do it with oops way , else i can do it.

Error : **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mysqli' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in customer.php on line 4**

**Index.php**

```
$adduser= new Userclass();
echo $adduser->addcutomer();
```

**Db class.php**

```
class db extends mysqli {
    private static $instance = null;
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "xxx";
    private $dbName = "xxx";
    private $dbHost = "localhost";

    public static function getInstance() {
    if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self;
    }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public function __clone() {
        trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    public function __wakeup() {
        trigger_error('Deserializing is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    private function __construct() {
        parent::__construct($this->dbHost, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbName);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                    . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        parent::set_charset('utf-8');
   }

    public function dbquery($query)
    {
        if($this->query($query))
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

**Customer Class**

```
class Userclass extends db{
  $mysqli=db::getInstance();

  public function addcutomer(){

    $query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (`firstname`,`lastname`) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $col1 = 'abc';
    $col2 = 'def';
    $query->bind_param('ss', $col1, $col2);
    $query->execute();
    $query->close();
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: pass $col1 = abc;
    $col2 = def; this in string like $col1 = 'abc'; $col2 = 'def';

Comment: You need to check the manual on how to set and access object properties. Also note that it is highly unlikely that you want all your classes to extend `mysqli`. You should take a look at dependency injection instead.

Comment: @jeroen , please help me with above code , seems some tweaking needed in db.php or customerclass.php

Answer (score -1):

Try this, hope this work

```
$col1 = "abc";
$col2 = "def";
```

Comment: update my question please help me to fix it

Comment: are you getting any error ?